# Having troubles to save image in django from nextjs in a two step request process

Tags: image, rest, next.js, django-rest-framework

I am having some trouble in my project when I try to save image from my nextj to my django server.I am aslo using redux toolkit

I am trying to update user profile information but I am having a challenge to get to save the user profile image
The request to update the userprofile is going through two steps, first from my component to my nextjs server, and then from there to my django server

In my component I am preparing the data for the update like this:

```
    const [
        updateUserProfile,
        { isSuccess: isUpdateSuccess, isLoading, error, isError },
      ] = useUpdateUserProfileMutation();


      const saveProfileImage = async () => {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("profile_image", file);
          formData.append("about", about);
          formData.append("country", country);
          formData.append("gender", gender);
          try {
        await updateUserProfile(formData);
          } catch (err) {
        console.error("Failed to update image: ", err);
        toast.error("Failed to update", {
          autoClose: 5000,
          position: "top-center",
          hideProgressBar: true,
        });
          }
      };
```

This is the mutation for the useUpdateUserProfileMutation():

```
  
    updateUserProfile: builder.mutation({
      query: (body) => ({
        url: "/auth/update_profile",
        method: "POST",
        body,
      }),
    }),
```

This useUpdateUserProfileMutation() is sending the request to the nextjs api server here :

```
  
    import { API_URL } from "../../../config/index";
    import cookie from "cookie";
    import axios from "axios";

    export default async (req, res) => {
      if (req.method === "POST") {
        const cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie ?? "");
        const access = cookies.access ?? false;

        const body = req.body

        try {
          const apiRes = await axios.put(`${API_URL}/user_profiles/update_profile/`, body, {
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${access}`,
        },
          });
          const data = await apiRes.data;

          if (apiRes.status === 200) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          user: data,
        });
          } else {
        return res.status(apiRes.status).json({
          error: data.error,
        });
          }
        } catch (err) {
          return res.status(500).json({
        error: err,
          });
        }
      } else {
        res.setHeader("Allow", ["POST"]);
        return res.status(405).json({
          error: `Method ${req.method} not allowed`,
        });
      }
    };
```

And then from this nextjs server, the request is then sent to the django so the data can be saved in the database, I am doing having these multiple steps because I want the request to be authenticated since I am using http only cookies that are saved in the nextjs server so that's why I am doing this.
But now the problem is  when the request reaches the django server, the request body is like this:

```
     00:00�\x033�\x00\x00\x00%tEXtdate:modify\x002023-06-05T11:41:50 00:00�^� \x00\x00\x00(tEXtdate:timestamp\x002023-06-05T11:41:50 00:00�K��\x00\x00\x008tEXticc:copyright\x00Copyright (c) 1998 Hewlett-Packard Company�Wy7\x00\x00\x00!tEXticc:description\x00sRGB IEC61966-2.1W��G\x00\x00\x00'], 'tEXticc:manufacturer\x00IEC http://www.iec.ch\x1c\x7f\x00L\x00\x00\x007tEXticc:model\x00IEC 61966-2.1 Default RGB colour space - sRGBDSH�\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND�B`�\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryZioAyJF1PSGb1onc\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': ['"about"\r\n\r\nMy bio edited\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryZioAyJF1PSGb1onc\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="country"\r\n\r\n7\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryZioAyJF1PSGb1onc\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="gender"\r\n\r\nmale\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryZioAyJF1PSGb1onc--\r\n']}>
    [16/Jun/2023 11:16:58] "PUT /user_profiles/update_profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 442
```

It's returning a 200 response but nothing is being saved, I guess its not reading the format well. How can I fix this. Also is there a better approach to this entire process?.
I have some other update request that are doing the 2 steps which does'nt include images and they are saving well without any problem.

Comment: In your NextJS API server code, try adding `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` to the axios PUT request headers.